# Can i update Library columns values when SharePoint site storage quota is already full?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, storage, sharepoint-online, quota

I have a query related to SharePoint Online Site storage Quota.

My customer has a site where the maximum site storage limit is already reached, but we have to update Libraries columns with system Update through a c# web job.

My customer has 20 libraries and each library has millions of documents, so customer wants to know if the system updates on documents Columns values will be impacted due to site storage limit is full, or it will not have any impact as it is column updates not a file udpate?

Can any one please share some information around it?

As per Microsoft documentations, new files can't be added and existing files can't be edited when site storage quota is full, but it is nowhere mentioned about site column updates.

Comment: Everything will depend on what type of content you want to update https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms452896(v=office.14)
Columns is a part of some content type.

Comment: I am not sure content type matters here.

Comment: I am not sure content type matters here. In my case i have a custom content type, and a web job will be updating metadata of 2 columns.
As the web job will process millions of documents metadata,  that is why i am looking for confirmation whether it will fail in between due to site storage issues or not.

Comment: All types in sharepoint are inherited from the base ones. The first part of any type indicates the base type, see the link I provided above. Since your question is extremely vague, I can only suggest that you set up a test environment and try running jobs in it.